# jQuery UI - Draggable not working right after dropped

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

HTML:

```
<div class="character_list">
   <div id="draggable" class="character_list_container">
      <div><img  class="1" src="http://ahna.web44.net//img/charas/13.png" /></div>
      <div><img class="2" src="http://ahna.web44.net//img/charas/13.png" /></div>
      <div><img class="3" src="http://ahna.web44.net//img/charas/13.png" /></div>
      <div><img  class="4" src="http://ahna.web44.net//img/charas/13.png" /></div>
      <div><img class="5" src="http://ahna.web44.net//img/charas/13.png" /></div>
      <div><img class="6" src="http://ahna.web44.net//img/charas/13.png" /></div>
   </div>
   <div id="droppable_slots" class="current_team">
      <div id="slot" class="1">1</div>
      <div id="slot" class="2">2</div>
      <div id="slot" class="3">3</div>
   </div>
</div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable>div>img").draggable({
        start: function(){
           $(this).css({display: 'none'});
        },
        stop: function(){
           $(this).css({display: 'block'});
        },
        revert: function(dropped) {
           var dropped = dropped && dropped[0].id== "slot";
           if(!dropped) {
              $(this).appendTo($(this).data('originalParent'))
            }
            return !dropped;
        },
        helper: function() { return $(this).clone().appendTo('body').show(); },
        containment: '.sel_screen_left'
}).each(function() {
    $(this).data('originalParent', $(this).parent())
});

$("#droppable_slots>div").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {

        var $this = $(this);
    var content = $.trim($this.html()).length;
    if(content > 0) {
    $this.html("");
    }
        $this.append(ui.draggable);    

        var width = $this.width();
        var height = $this.height();
        var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - (ui.draggable.width() / 2);
        var cntrTop = (height / 2) - (ui.draggable.height() / 2);

        ui.draggable.css({
            left: cntrLeft + "px",
            top: cntrTop + "px"
        });

}
});
});​
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/CVbzg/3/

As you can see in the jsfiddle example, when an image is dropped it locks in perfectly however when you move out of the drop zone it loses the draggability rather than reverting and appending to its original parent.

Can someone help?

Comment: Duplicated IDs are invalid btw.

Comment: It is not your main problem, but you've assigned the `slot` ID to 3 elements. It is invalid HTML and all but the first element with that ID can't be accessed using that ID.

Comment: how would I go about fixing it? the revert code uses it to check if it's a valid drop point.

Comment: Can make it a class and check with `hasClass`. I couldn't reproduce your "losing draggability" issue, the only issue I noticed was it animating the revert backwards due to your appending it to the original container in the middle of the revert. That could be bluntly solved by removing that effect with a `revertDuration:0`. Here's a fiddle without duplicated IDs and no animation: http://jsfiddle.net/CVbzg/4/

Comment: Oh when you move out a little bit only it loses draggability. Also if you drop one inside of another they disappear.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted as far as animation goes, and thanks for the syntax fix! Any idea on why the drag stops working though?

Comment: The more important one being the image losing draggability

Comment: It's like the clone that is created just stops dragging and doesnt revert to it's old spot, im guessing that's due to the revert overwrite but that's not possible since the clone is supposed to be removed.

Comment: Yeah, just submitted an answer. Check it out and test the fiddle. `=]`

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted! I can't vote up because of rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move the droppable a little bit after it is already placed in the drop target and it loses draggability, it is because of

```
$this.html("");
```

In the drop handler, the draggable is still inside the drop target. When you erase the drop target's HTML, you also remove the element which is supposed to be re-appended. This returns a syntax error as the element is no longer there which breaks the operation leaving the clone there and the draggable erased.

Here's a quick fix:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.find('.ui-draggable').length) return; //don't overwrite occupied spot
    $this.empty(); //empty() sounds more semantic than html('') for me, it does the same thing =]
    $this.append(ui.draggable);
    //...
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CVbzg/6/)

It won't allow overwriting a dropped element inside of a drop target by another element, which includes re-dropping elements on their own drop targets.

---

An alternative solution is to move the already dropped draggable back to its starting position before appending the draggable being dropped:

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
    var $this = $(this),
        containsDropped = $this.find('.ui-draggable');
    if (containsDropped.length) containsDropped.appendTo(containsDropped.data('originalParent'));
    $this.empty();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CVbzg/8/)

You just have to take care to not erase a draggable unintentionally. `=]`

Comment: Why does the 1,2,3 disappear when you put a draggable on then take it off?

Comment: @CodyGuldner Because OP is calling `.html('')`/`.empty()` on the drop targets in the drop handler. Not sure whether that was intended or not.

Comment: I want to use this code, but do you know if there is a way to make it so that if you drag the image onto one of the boxes, it redirects to another page?

Comment: Sure, in the `drop:` function identify which image you dropped or in which container it was dropped (according to your own criteria) and call `location = 'http://redict.to/path';`

Comment: I am not going to be using images, I want to make a dragable menu. (sorry for spamming this. I was banned from questions). See here http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/PCQ62/

Comment: @CodyGuldner JSFiddle is giving me some weird errors, but check if this is close to what you want: http://jsbin.com/iluvuh/1/edit Used `data-address` in the html to specify which page to redirect to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22219/discussion-between-cody-guldner-and-fabricio-matte)