# jQuery droppable - allow only one item to be dropped on an element and then make the dropped one draggable again

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

with [jQuery droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/), I have multiple draggables and droppable as well. Only one draggable should be allowed to be dropped on an element at a time. However, after dropping, the draggable should be given the dragging capability again.
The problem I am facing is that multiple draggable can be dropped on one element.  My code follows:

```
<div id="draggable_all" style="float: left;  width: 300px;">
<div class="draggable">drag1111</div>
<div class="draggable">drag2222</div>
<div class="draggable">drag3333</div>
</div>

<div id="droppable_all" style="float: left; width:300px; ">



<div class="droppable"></div>
<div class="droppable"></div>
<div class="droppable"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 <style type="text/css">
        .droppable {
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            background: red;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            /*position: absolute;*/
            /*right: 0;*/
            /*bottom: 0;*/
        }
        .draggable {
            /*position: absolute;*/
            z-index: 9;
            /*top: 25px;*/
            /*left: 20px;*/
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            background-color: green;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
    </style>
```

and JS:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: handleRevert
    });

    $(".draggable").data("orDraggable",$(".draggable").offset());

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: handleDropEvent
        //,
        // out: function(event, ui){
        //     $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.drag-item');
        // }
    });

    function handleRevert(e) {
        if (e === false) {
            $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = $(this).data("orDraggable");
            return true
        }
    }

    function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.position({
            of: $(this),
            my: 'left top',
            at: 'left top'
        });

        //$(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
       // $(this).droppable('disable');


    }

});
```

How to achieve that ?

PS: SO has similar questions but none solves my problem well. For example , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14167965/jquery-ui-draggable-not-working-right-after-dropped) question tries to solve it. But the problem here is : the dropped element does not have the same alignment against the element on which it is dropped.

**EDIT:**
  I made a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsf_user/xpvt214o/447571/) with a bit change in CSS.

Comment: In your drop, disable the droppable. You can then enable it in drag start.

Comment: @Twisty, how to enable it in drag start ? any code ?

Comment: @Twisty, my  `drop` event calls function `handleDrropEvent`. So I can add at the end of the function this line : `$(".droppable").droppable("disable");`. Am I right ?

Comment: Can the draggables be dropped only into droppables, or anywhere else?

Comment: @TJ, on droppables only

Comment: Then you could use the `accept: function(){}` to decide whether to accept or not. On drop, add a `disabled` class to droppable. Then in accept return false if the class is present. You will need to remove the class when the draggable is dropped into another droppable (somehow check which droppable was holding the dragged item previously on drop, then remove the `disabled` class from it so it can accept new draggables, using a `data-*` attribute for example.

Comment: @TJ, can you provide the code snippet ?

Comment: @TJ, code would make things more clear

Comment: Please make a snippet, fiddle or something with your attempt and mention what is missing so we can play with it

Comment: @TJ, Added an 'EDIT' to my OP. The jsfiddle is here : https://jsfiddle.net/jsf_user/xpvt214o/447571/

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can disable or destroy Droppable when the item is dropped. This will prevent further drops. You can also change the `accept` option so that it will not accept any more if you like.

Here is an example of the first solutions: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/upfy74tw/12/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function handleRevert(e) {
    var $t = $(this);
    if (e === false) {
      $t.data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = $t.data("orDraggable");
      return true
    }
  }

  function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
    var $self = $(this);
    var $item = ui.draggable;
    $item.position({
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'left top',
      of: $self
    });
    $self.droppable("destroy");
    $item.appendTo($self).attr("style", "");
    $item.draggable("destroy");
    $item.draggable({
      start: function() {
        $self.droppable({
          drop: handleDropEvent
        });
      }
    })
  }

  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: handleRevert
  });

  $(".draggable").data("orDraggable", $(".draggable").offset());

  $(".droppable").droppable({
    drop: handleDropEvent
  });
});
```

There are a few things going on in your drop event.

1. Destroy droppable
2. Align the draggable and then append it to the container
3. Destroy draggable
4. Assign Draggable and re-assign Droppable at start of `drag` event

Hope that helps.